# Challenges with high cardinality data

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, dimensionality-reduction, cardinality

**Background**: I am working on classifying data from a ticketing system data into a failed or successful requests. A request goes into various stages before getting completed. Each request is assigned to different teams and individuals before being marked as complete. 
Making use of historical data I want to create predictions for these tickets at a final state x before they are marked as complete(success or fail).

Amongst the various features, individual's name who work on the records & team names are very important factors in analysing this data. Being a huge organization I expect 5-10 new names being added every day.

**Historical data**

60k records (used for training, validation and testing)
Has 10k unique individual names

**Current data**
Overal 1k records
- Has 200 individual names

I'm facing a challenge due to high cardinality data like individual names whose number is not fixed and keeps on growing.
1. Challenge while making actual predictions - The no. of columns for the current data will be different every time and would never match the feature length of training data. 
- So I have to train my model every single time, I want to make predictions.
2. Challenge while data prep -  The above also presents a challenge for data prep as now I always have to encode the complete data and the query encoded data to split into current and future data.

Sorry for the long story.

**What am I looking for?**

Is there a better way to approach? 
These high & constantly changing dimensions is a pain. Any suggestions on how can I handle them, to avoid training every time?

Note: I tried using PCA and Autoencoders for dim red. (The results were not great for my highly unbalanced dataset so I'm working on the data with high dimensions only)

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace all id numbers and names in the data with a standard token like `<ID>` or `<NAME>`. This should be done during preprocessing. Next you should pick a fixed vocabulary. Like all words that occur at least 5 times in the training data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a dynamic data like you said, you can use neural net to identify and merge updating variables and data.

Also you should use classifiers like

1. CVParameterSelection : For cross validation parameter selection.
2. PART : For making a decision tree, great utility as it works on divide and conquer rule.
3. REP Tree (Pruned) : For reduced error in output by splitting error values

And finally when you have the systems in place, you can run the prediction model!